# Container Component not updating on action

Tags: redux

I have the following reducer:

```
const selectEntityReducer = function(entityState, action) {
    const selectedEntity = entityState.allEntities.filter(e => (e.id == action.id))[0]
    const newStateForSelectEntity = updateObject(entityState, {selectedEntity: selectedEntity});
    return newStateForSelectEntity;
};
```

`entityState` shape looks like `{entities:[{id:1}, {id:2}], selectedEntity:{id:2}}`.

I have a React component that is connected to the store like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        selectEntity: state.entities.selectEntity
    };
}
```

However, it never re-renders.

If I say `selectEntities: state.entities` in `mapStateToProps`, then the component re-renders.  But I'm only interested in the selected entity for this component.

I'm aware that enforcing immutability down the entire state tree is required for redux to function properly.  But I thought that is what I was doing in `selectEntityReducer`.

---

Any extra context can be seen in the full redux code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/AlexanderBollbach/fdd8498d47b00dfbd99517200a7b64ed).

Comment: Entity state has `selectedEntity` but in `mapStateToProps` you are returning `selectEntity`. Could this be the reason?

Comment: i just read about immutability in javascript for an hour to be told it was a typo!?  omg.. thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Its happens because you filter old piece of state. 
You must copy your entities:

```
const newEntities = entityState.allEntities.slice();
const newSelectedentities = newEntities.filter.........
```

Copy piece of ctate if it array and then process it.